# Cypress: Check if an element contains a specific other element

Tags: cypress

I need to check a div to see if it contains an 'a' (link). I've been looking at similar questions here, but none seem to do exactly what I'm trying.

Example markup:

```
<div if='description>
  blablablabla
  blablablabla
  blablablabla
</div>
<div id='description'>
  blablablabla
  <a href="thelink">The link</a>
  blablablabla
</div>
<div id='description>
  blablablabla
  blablablabla
  blablablabla
</div>
```

The ids are duplicated, and there's nothing I can do about that. However, using .eq() in these cases seems to work fine.

What I need to do, is to check, for instance, cy.get('#description').eq(0) to see if there is an 'a' within it, and click it if there is. If there is no 'a', do nothing.

I've tried things like this, without success:

```
if (cy.get('#description').eq(0).contains('a')) {
  cy.get('#description').eq(0).within( () => {
      cy.get('a').click();
  });
```

Probably incorrect code anyway, with regards to the use of within.

This, too:

```
if (cy.get('#description').eq(0).children().contains('a')) {
  cy.get('#description').eq(0).within( () => {
    cy.get('a').click();
  });
```

All help and/or hints are, as allways, appreciated. (Man, I miss Selenium sometimes, where I could use Java or Kotlin code with near full freedom.)

Comment: You can pass a selector to `children()`, so I guess `cy.get('#description').eq(0).children('a')` should work.

Comment: Well, what I'm asking is not how to get the element if it exists in the <div>, but how to click it IF it exists, and do nothing if it doesn't.

Comment: Sure, but you need to get the element in order to click it. And the way you're trying to get the element is wrong: `contains('a')` doesn't retrieve the `a` element, it retrieves an element that contains the "a" string. @Alapan's answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use children for this as mentioned by @lbsn and then add `click()`.

```js
cy.get('#description').eq(0).children('a').click()
```

You can also look into this, like when you get the `a` then click on it and exit `each()` and if there is no child element, the test continues and doesn't fail.

```js
cy.get('div#description').each(($ele) => {
  if ($ele.children('a').length > 0) {
    cy.wrap($ele).children('a').click()
    return false //Remove if you want to continue the loop even after finding the child element
  }
})
```

Comment: That won't work when there IS no 'a', which is kind of the essence of my question. I need to click the link IF it exists; if it doesn't, the test shouldn't fail (since both are ok).

Comment: Updated the answer. Can you check.

Comment: Yes! That does it! Thanks! :-)

Comment: Hey, that's great!